# Is it possible to set the ValidationAttribute.ErrorMessage value when an object is instantiated?

Tags: c#

I have a class with a Required attribute and an ErrorMessage:

```
public class Color
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Select Color")]   
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

I'm using objects of the class in two different dropdowns and would like to change the validation error message that is displayed to be specific to the dropdown. So for one dropdown the message would be "Please Select New Color" and for the other dropdown the message would be "Please Select Old Color".

So when I create an object as shown below, can I also set the ErrorMessage on the Required Attribute?

```
Fruit newFruit = new Fruit()
{
   Id = 1,
   Name = "Apple"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Values passed to attributes must be known to the compiler at compile
>   time.

source: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177221.aspx)

So I guess this way you cannot, but you can change the errormessage in other places, or use an ErrorMessage property in your class.

*Suggestion 1:*

```
// in class
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select {0} color")]   
public int Id { get; set; } 

//gui
string errormessage = ""; //get errormessage here
string state = "old" //get state;
errormessage = string.Format(errormessage, state);
//set errormessage
```

*Suggestion 2:*

[How to customize validation attribute error message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17474823/how-to-customize-validation-attribute-error-message)

Comment: In what other places can I change the errormessage?

Comment: What do you use besides c#, where are your dropdowns?

Comment: I'm using Jquery to populate one of the dropdowns

Comment: So do you let asp.net populate your dropowns, or are you setting them yourself? Would be nice if you'd provide some GUI code, since I guess there is the problem for you.